# I am getting duplicate entries when joining 3 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is my query

```
SELECT d.fullName
     , d.mobileNumber
     , t.hospitalId
     , t.doctorId
     , s.startTime
     , s.endTime
  FROM tbl_doctors d
  JOIN tbl_doctors_duty_time t
    ON t.hospitalId = d.hospitalId 
   AND t.hospitalId = 213 
   AND d.active = 1
  JOIN tbl_time_slot s
    ON s.doctorDutyTimeId = t.id 
   AND s.active = 1
```

I am getting output

```
fullName mobileNumber hospitalId doctorId startTime endTime
babu      76867          213        9      00:00:02 00:00:03
mahesh     55            213        9      00:00:02 00:00:03
babu      76867          213       25      00:00:06 00:00:09
mahesh     55            213       25      00:00:06 00:00:09
```

My expecting Output

```
fullName mobileNumber hospitalId doctorId startTime endTime
babu      76867          213        9      00:00:02 00:00:03
mahesh     55            213       25      00:00:06 00:00:09
```

Is it correct query for joining 3 tables?? I am getting multiple entries and doctor ID, startTime and endTime is not coming right place

Sample Data
Table tbl_doctors

```
 doctorId active fullName hospitalId mobileNumber
   9       1      babu      213       76867
   25      1     mahesh     213       55
```

Table doctors_duty_time

```
# id    active hospitalId doctorId advanceBookingDays
  2     1        213       9       10    
  3     1        213       25      11
```

Table tbl_time_slot

```
#id   active startTime endTime   tokenLimit doctorDutyTimeId
2      1      00:00:02 00:00:03   10          2
3      1      00:00:06 00:00:09   10           3
```

Comment: Sample data please,,

Comment: You need to join `tbl_doctors_duty_time` by `doctorId`, but not by `hospitalId`

Comment: Yor `tbl_doctors` and `tbl_doctors_duty_time` tables are joined only by `hospitalId`. You probably want to join by the `doctorId` also.

Comment: you need to move the conditions after each AND in the WHERE section of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table `tbl_doctors_duty_time` there is a column `doctorId` on which you should also join the tables `tbl_doctors` and `tbl_doctors_duty_time`:

```
SELECT  tbl_doctors.fullName,tbl_doctors.mobileNumber,
        tbl_doctors_duty_time.hospitalId,
        tbl_doctors_duty_time.doctorId,
        tbl_time_slot.startTime,tbl_time_slot.endTime
FROM tbl_doctors INNER JOIN tbl_doctors_duty_time 
ON tbl_doctors_duty_time.hospitalId = tbl_doctors.hospitalId 
        AND tbl_doctors_duty_time.doctorId = tbl_doctors.doctorId
        AND tbl_doctors_duty_time.hospitalId = 213 
        AND tbl_doctors.active =1
    INNER JOIN tbl_time_slot ON tbl_time_slot.doctorDutyTimeId = tbl_doctors_duty_time.id 
        AND tbl_time_slot.active =1
```

In this condition:

```
tbl_doctors_duty_time.doctorId = tbl_doctors.doctorId
```

I assumed that the column name in the table `tbl_doctors` is `doctorId`, so change it to the actual name.
Here is another version of the query with the use of aliases and conditions in the `WHERE` clause, so the code is more readable:

```
SELECT  d.fullName, d.mobileNumber,
        dt.hospitalId, dt.doctorId,
        ts.startTime, ts.endTime
FROM tbl_doctors AS d 
INNER JOIN tbl_doctors_duty_time AS dt
ON dt.hospitalId = d.hospitalId AND dt.doctorId = d.doctorId
INNER JOIN tbl_time_slot AS ts 
ON ts.doctorDutyTimeId = dt.id
WHERE dt.hospitalId = 213 AND d.active = 1 AND ts.active = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/91H6T9P93PWR5fapabc7yR/0).
Results:

```
| fullName | mobileNumber | hospitalId | doctorId | startTime | endTime  |
| -------- | ------------ | ---------- | -------- | --------- | -------- |
| babu     | 76867        | 213        | 9        | 00:00:02  | 00:00:03 |
| mahesh   | 55           | 213        | 25       | 00:00:06  | 00:00:09 |
```